# Everything get [Permission Denied] Ubuntu Core

Tags: permissions, ubuntu-core, raspberrypi

I can't save anything on my raspberry running ubuntu core. I just installed the new version and NOTHING saves.
Not even creating a new file on my home directory. Even as `root`!

The only workaround that I found so far (I tried many) is to install the docker snap, mount my working directory as a volume of a container and run any editor from inside the container.

Why is this happening?

EDIT: I'm using the [ubuntu core for raspberry pi from the ubuntu website](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/iot/raspberry-pi-2-3). I followed the exact steps on that page for the installation.
The raspberry is the 3 model B+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should have been a comment but my reputation is too low.

I have just done the same thing, e.g. Ubuntu Core 16 on a Raspberry Pi 3 and it worked from the start.
I followed the instructions on
[Create installation medias for Ubuntu Core](https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/installation-medias)
[Raspberry Pi 2 or 3](https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/raspberry-pi-2-3)
So when you log on with ssh does it display the expected welcome screen?

> Welcome to Ubuntu Core 16 (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-1102-raspi2 armv7l)  *
>   Ubuntu Core:     https://www.ubuntu.com/core  * Community:
>   https://forum.snapcraft.io  * Snaps:           https://snapcraft.io

And if you touch a new file:

```
igor-lopez@localhost:~$ touch test  
igor-lopez@localhost:~$ ls -lart test  
-rw-rw-r-- 1 igor-lopez igor-lopez 0 Jan  6 08:55 test
```

What is the response?

To get nano working on Ubuntu Core 16 I had to install the classic snap

```
$ sudo snap install classic --edge --devmode
```

where you have to adapt for Ubuntu Core 18 as you wrote in the comment below.

Comment: The welcome message you pasted here is for Ubuntu Core 16. That one works. My problem started on Ubuntu Core 18, some commands touch and ls work for some reason. But vi/vim and nano doesn't.

Comment: Also `echo "Something" > test` works but `echo "Something" >> test` don't. So I do have access to the files, but any editor I try cannot save and shows permission denied

Comment: Big oops, I actually thought I had Ubuntu Core 18 but I see now it is 16. Anyway I only have nano working under "sudo classic", e.g. I first installed:  `sudo snap install classic --edge --devmode` and then running it after starting with `sudo classic`. I the edit files in my home directory before exiting the classic mode and copy the edited file to proper location.

Comment: And now I found my mistake, it's the classic snap. The `--edge` option goes to the default edge channel, which is 16.04, I need to use the channel 18/edge of classic on Core 18. Thanks man

Comment: Just so things don't get messy here, would you mind adding that to you answer or sending another one for me to accept? So anyone that gets here don't have to check the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed or did you boot the demo?

If you have installed, delete ubuntu and and any partitions on your HDD. Run the demo and make new partitions like so:https://www.linuxliteos.com/forums/installing-linux-lite/partition-alignment-prompt-at-install/

Install ubuntu and make sure you have it set to NO PASSWORD

Comment: Is there a demo mode of the ubuntu core? I followed the installation steps for my raspberry pi 3 on the ubuntu official site. I normally do what you suggested on ubuntu desktop installation

Comment: There should be if you haven't installed it yet. It should be like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtoGV.jpg

Comment: That screen is not present in the installation of ubuntu core. I added the link to the ubuntu website page that I used to install it. I've tried reinstalling it more than once.